Navigating Color Choices for a Hospital System Design as a Frontend Developer
I am a frontend developer and I am going to create a fairly huge system for hospitals. Since my designing skills are limited, and mostly used for sites, I need some help and resources to start my work.
The first thing I am having trouble making is deciding the colors I am using. Initially, I am thinking only black and white with grays inbetween. I've learned you should start with a color, let's say white, and change it a bit until you have a palette from white to black. I tried doing that but I don't know if those colors are gonna fit within my design, they don't look good (I don't have the necessary skills to say why, but if need I can provide the colors I came up with, if this stack allows for that). This led me to think that maybe I should create some screens first and see what goes better, then I'd pick those colors as patterns for all my future screens.
Also, should I have specific colors for borders and backgrounds, texts and icons... like group colors based on their function inside my layout? That seems like a good idea, since the project is big and requires patterns, but I don't how to do that yet.
Besides the black/white palette, my user will be able to set a personalized color for his system, and I am afraid of that, so I am thinking about using this accent color very rarely, to be sure nothing will come out too bad because of a user's poor choice.
For now, I just need some help with the colors. I am doing a designers' job because I am the frontend developer of the projetct and creating layout from code, on the fly, is too complicated and makes the process very truncated.

Hey Bernardo. This is much too broad of a question for the Q&A format. As such, your question is likely to be closed

To reiterate my comment from your last post, there's no hope for you to design a good system by yourself without intimate knowledge of their needs and requirements. It'd also help to have experience designing these systems before. As such, I highly recommend that you try and seek the ability to hire a designer that has experience in these areas.

@ZachSaucier, I get that, but I figured I'll have to show some layout before my company decides to hire a designer. Their references for layout are too old and they think what I have done already is good, while I think otherwise... At this point, I can help only by trying to show that there's more than what they know, and I think doing some nice layouts with the features we already have (improving the flow for the user maybe) will show them that.

Have a look at this question: Is there a good resource or tool to help build a palette/color scheme around colors I select?. Lots of excellent resources here.
